# How do I sum values in array when the values are strings

Tags: javascript, html

I have this array:

```
shipPrice: [["17.50"], ["7.00"]]
shippingFrom : ["SARAWAK", "KUALA LUMPUR"]
```

I complete the simple looping function and appear in html view.

I have tried :

```js
const data = {
  countTotal: 2,
  shipPrice: [
    ["17.50"],
    ["7.00"]
  ],
  shippingFrom: ["SARAWAK", "KUALA LUMPUR"]
}
var totalShipping = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.countTotal; i++) {
  $("#ShippingFromJson").append('<li id="ShippingFromJson">' + data.shippingFrom[i] + '<span id="ShippingPriceJson">RM ' + data.shipPrice[i] + '</span></li>');
  totalShipping += data.shipPrice[i];
}
$("#isTotal").html(totalShipping);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ShippingFromJson"></ul>
<span id="isTotal"></span>
```

Output is
017.507.00

It should be 24.5

Help please

Comment: it appears that `data.shipPrice` are strings. you need to convert them to `Number` before adding them. otherwise, you're concatenating strings.

Comment: Output clearly shows strings concatenation and not mathematical operation was performed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with AJAX

Comment: Also you create multiple identical IDs.

Comment: Try this: `let totalShipping = 0, html = ''; for (let i = 0; i < data.countTotal; i++) {
html += \`<li class="ShippingFromJson">${data.shippingFrom[i]} <span class="ShippingPriceJson">RM ${data.shipPrice[i]}</span></li>\`;   totalShipping += +data.shipPrice[i]; } $("#ShippingFromJson").append(html); $("#isTotal").text(totalShipping.toFixed(2));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `shipPrice` is array of string it will concat the data and not perform arithmetic operation with +. For this [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat) can solve your problem. See the following example.

```js
var data = {
  "countTotal": 2,
  "shipPrice": [
    ["17.50"],
    ["7.00"]
  ],
  "shippingFrom": ["SARAWAK", "KUALA LUMPUR"]
};


var totalShipping = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < data.countTotal; i++) {

  $("#ShippingFromJson").append('<li id="ShippingFromJson">' + data.shippingFrom[i] + '<span id="ShippingPriceJson">RM ' + data.shipPrice[i] + '</span></li>');


  totalShipping += parseFloat(data.shipPrice[i]);

}
$("#isTotal").html(totalShipping);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ShippingFromJson"></ul>
<div id="isTotal"></div>
```

Comment: thank so much @Kiran 
totalShipping += parseFloat(data.shipPrice[i]);